# how can i save the current HTML page locally via a button on page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very big `HTML page` with many large tables. 
I have tried to export the `tables to excel` and succeeded. But when dealing with `200K+ rows` in a table, the browser crashes (Chrome and IE).
So, I have decided to save the entire page locally.

Can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: File -> Save Page As?

Comment: what exactly do you want to save? just the raw HTML code? or the whole page including images, css, js?

Comment: Whole page locally..

Comment: @SergChernata exactly the same as File -> Save Page As...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a download button that anyone can use on your site to save a file, use the `download` attribute.

```
<a href='link.html' download>text</a>
```

Comment: This would work if its a static page... But not supported in old browsers including Edge 12, IE, Safari or Opera 12

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the data that is in these tables is loaded from your server somewhere. Wouldn't it be better to create a downloadlink to an action on your server that creates these files instead of creating the files based on your html page?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to load the page in your browser and then go to **File > Save As**.  This will open a dialoge that allows you to save the page as an html type file.

However if the webpage is so large that the browser cannot load it, use a tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) on linux to pull the entire page down without using a browser.  After installing wget on a linux distribution, use it like so

> wget http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html

This command will download the file to the current directory with name `file.html`

If you also want to download any included files in `file.html` (ie css or js files). Include the flags `-p` and `-k`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called download-page-test.html as seen below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Look at this page.</h1>
    <h1>It's so plain!</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href='/download-page-test.html' download>Click Here to Download</a>
</body>
```

When the user clicks on the word "text", the browser downloads the same exact file that is served to the browser as well as the JS/CSS for the page (Granted you don't move/delete the external resources). *Note:* I used BootStrap to make it look a bit nicer.

This solution is for a page that loads in the browser successfully and the user wants a copy.